# Check value between two times in my database php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a booking form where the users can book a certain facility, on a certain date and between two times.  I have come to a point where my PHP code will prevent the user from booking the same pitch on the same date and from the same start or end time.

However the user can go between a time and book the same facility on the same date as another user.  e.g. if one user has booked from 9 to 12 on the 1st May another user can come in and book the 10 or 11 slot.

Is there any way of preventing the user from booking a time between the time another user has already booked???

```
    <?php
        include "config.php"; 
        //Booking point
        if(isset($_POST['booking']))
        {
            //get values for variables
            $pitchID = $_POST['pitchID'];
            $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
            $start_hour = $_POST['start_hour'];
            $end_hour = $_POST['end_hour'];
            $booking_age = $_POST['booking_age'];
            $pitch_size = $_POST['pitch_size'];
            $light_tokens = $_POST['light_tokens'];


/*          $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE start_date = ?, start_hour = ?, end_hour=?, pitchID=?");
            $query = $q->execute(array($start_date, $start_hour, $end_hour, $pitchID));
            $count = $q->rowCount(); */
                $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE start_date = ? AND start_hour = ? AND pitchID = ?");
                $query = $q->execute(array($start_date, $start_hour, $pitchID));
                $count = $q->rowCount();

                if($count == 0){

                    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO booking SET pitchID = ?, start_date = ?, start_hour = ?, end_hour = ?, booking_age = ?, pitch_size = ?, light_tokens = ?, userID='$userID'");
                    $query = $query->execute(array($pitchID,$start_date,$start_hour,$end_hour,$booking_age,$pitch_size,$light_tokens));

                    if($query){
                        echo "Your booking has been made";
                        header("Location:home2_template.html");
                        return; 
                    } else {
                        echo "Fail";
                    } //else fail   
                } else {
                    echo "This booking already exists"; 
                } //else count 
        } //if booking
    ?>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Is there any way of preventing the user from booking a time between the time another user has already booked???

Comment: You can use between function PF mysql

Comment: I'm not using my SQL I'm developing in PDO

Comment: "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE start_date = ? AND pitchID = ? AND start_hour BETWEEN :start_hour AND :end_hour" I tried this but it gives me an error.  I'm obviously doing something wrong in the SQL but I don't know what?

Answer (score 1):

If you only can reserve one day, try this

```
select * from booking
where (start_date='new_date' 
        and ( 
                (start_hour <='new_start_hour' and end_hour>='new_start_hour') 
                or
                (start_hour<= 'new_end_hour' and end_hour>='new_end_hour')
            )
    ) and pitchID = ?
```

Comment: comment to OP: You need to use innodb tables and transactions to prevent concurrency problems (multiple users get the same time slot because they both book at the same moment in time and the ).

Comment: Sorry jpintor that didn't seem to work for me, it's still accepting bookings between another bookings time slot.  Do I need to insert the new_start_hour anywhere in my PHP code apart from the select statement

Comment: please show me the actual code and explain a bit more in what cases fail now